# problemas para subir datos a un select multiple usando multiselect bootstrap desde ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas necesito subir datos a un select multiple con ajax usando el plugins de jquery bootstrap-multiselect: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods con el metodo .multiselect('dataprovider', data). el formato de la varible data es un array de objetos. Lo que he echo hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#idpuntosAtencion").multiselect();

    function ajax(url, data, id, event) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                success: function (respuesta) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                  $(id).multiselect('dataprovider', respuesta);
                }
            });
        }, 900) 
    }
    $('#ciudadId').on('change',function(event){
          var data = {'ciudadId':$('#ciudadId').val()};
          ajax('Funtions/bloquerTurnoAll.php',data,'#idpuntosAtencion',event);
    });
    $('#idpuntosAtencion').on('change',function(event){
          var data = {'idpuntosAtencion':$('#idpuntosAtencion').val()};
          ajax('Funtions/bloquerTurnoAll.php',data,'#consultorioId',event);
    });

  });
```

bloquerTurnoAll.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['ciudadId']))
    {
        $query_puntoatencion = "SELECT puntosAtencion.idpuntosAtencion, puntosAtencion.nombre FROM puntosAtencion WHERE puntosAtencion.estado<>'I' AND puntosAtencion.ciudadId=$_POST[ciudadId]";
        $puntoatencion = mysqli_query($callcenter,$query_puntoatencion) or die(mysqli_error($callcenter));
        $row_puntoatencion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($puntoatencion);
        $totalRows_puntoatencion = mysqli_num_rows($puntoatencion);
        $option='';
        if ($totalRows_puntoatencion>0) {
            $option='[';
            do
            {
                $option.="{label: '".$row_puntoatencion['nombre']."', title: '".$row_puntoatencion['nombre']."', value: '".$row_puntoatencion['idpuntosAtencion']."'},";
            }
            while($row_puntoatencion = mysqli_fetch_assoc($puntoatencion));
            $option.=']';
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">Sin informacion para mostrar</option>';
        }
        echo $option;
    }
```

error en la consola: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

en el codigo php intento armar el formato de la variable data del plugins. me podrian ayudar con loque sucede en esto.

Answer (score 1):

En el código PHP te faltan las Comillas simples cuando seleccionas la ciudadId del post.

Comment: Por su parte primero prueba de forma individual el multiselect, luego si todo va bien añade la llamada ajax, luego si todo va bien agrega el timeout.

Comment: no por eso no hay problemas.. en la consulta no tengo incoveniente, es en armar el array de objeto que no pasa, me imagino que es por q la paso como una cadena string la variable option que es la respuesta en el codigo js

Comment: ya hice esas pruebas arme un array y lo coloque directamente en el js y el multiselect funciona carga los datos sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

No puedo comentar, pero ¿has intentado pasar `data` [como un string (JSON)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) y después de ello, convertir ese JSON en un objeto en tu php con [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)?.